# Bit masking using bit operation &

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

My textbook says

"The bitwise AND operator & is often used to mask off some set of bits, for example
n = n & 0177;
sets to zero all but the low-order 7 bits of n."

But, as per my understanding, binary form of 0177 is 101010001, so the operation n =n & 0177 should retain 1st, 5th , 7th and 9th bit of n from right, and set all other bits to zero.

Can anyone point out where am I wrong in understanding this?

Comment: 0177 is an *octal* constant.

Comment: [Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65018892/edit) to add a language tag would allow us to give you a link to the appropriate part of the language spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it would work when 0177 is an octal (base 8, 3 bits per digit) number.

In several languages (for instance javascript) a leading 0 signals an octal number:

```js
var n = 0177; // n now contains the decimal value 127
```

so octal 0177 == binary 01 111 111 == decimal 127

And this (0-prefix means octal) is also why in javascript a `parseInt` fails on a month input of `08` or `09`, unless you explicitly specify a radix of 10.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your understanding is correct aside from the binary representation of 0177. If this is a decimal number it would be 01111111 and if it were hex (as I suspect it is), don’t forget the 0x prefix! Then it is 101110111 so it would retain different bits. Not sure where you got 101010001. Let me know if this doesn’t make sense.

Comment: It would be `01111111` if the original representation is **octal** - *decimal* would be `10110001`.